# Is there a stable cross-platform softphone? Or a Linux-only one?

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip, pbx, softphone

We use an Asterisk based solution as our PBX, and although we've found hardphones work flawlessly, we have yet to find a reliable softphone.

The basic requirement is that it allows multiple calls and transfers.

I don't have a comprehensive list, but most of what we've tried adds delay to the voice (echo), garbles the sound, doesn't allow more than one call at a time, or just plain won't work.

On Windows we're fine (SJPhone), and although I'd prefer to use the same softphone for both OSes, I will settle for a good Linux-only one.

Any recommendations?

Comment: FYI, I've had problems getting SJPhone to work on Windows 7.  I usually use it with its profile "PC to PC (SIP)", although I can't remember offhand if the problems were profile specific or not.

Answer (score 3):

I have looked at quite a few of the soft phone clients one of my favorites is x-lite
http://www.counterpath.net/x-lite-download.html I don't like that you can't transfer (with the free version) but it seems to be a very solid client. You should also check out this comparison http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_VoIP_software

Comment: x-lite doesn't run on Linux :(

Comment: so Ivan, you're saying that http://storage.counterpath.com/downloads/X-Lite_Install.tar.gz isn't linux compatible?

Comment: No, I'm saying I didn't see Linux on the requirements, but thanks for the link!

Comment: I have never tried to run it on linux but they do say they have a linux build

Answer (score 3):

I have had good success using [ZoIPer](http://www.zoiper.com) (formerly idefisk) under both Linux and Windows.

One major advantage of that client is that it supports both IAX and SIP. The free version supports two line registration profiles and they have paid versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I know of is [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/).  Never used it so can't give a recommendation one way or the other.

Comment: We've tried that. It doesn't run well.

Comment: It might have been helpful (and saved some peoples' time) if you had listed the ones you had already tried and why they were not suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't keep a list as I said, but I do remember some names when I see them. You didn't even try your own suggestion so I don't know why you complain ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Twinkle](http://www.twinklephone.com/) works absolutely fine for me on Linux.

Comment: This is the only one that seems to be happy running under pulseaudio (even though it goes through ALSA first).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the [Linux version of SJPhone](http://www.sjlabs.com/sjp.html) wasn't suitable then?

[X-Lite](http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite.html) is great for a free solution. If you're willing to part with some cash for a license then [eyeBeam](http://www.counterpath.net/eyebeam.html) is reasonably priced.

Comment: Nope, SJPhone didn't work reliably. And x-lite doesn't run on Linux.

Comment: http://www.counterpath.net/x-lite-download.html - Linux/Mac/PC

Comment: Yep, sorry, didn't see that... Is eyeBeam available too? It seems it isn't.